# Compilation error while merging two Maps is being issued for Map.Entry::getKey

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, method-reference

Whenever I use `Map.Entry::getKey` in my streams for my public methods, I get an issue around my method not being `static`. I even tried making my method `static`, and it didn't work.

Below is the compile **error** I am getting from using `Map.Entry()::getKey()` :

```
Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

**My code**

```
/***
 * Merge 2 Maps and add the values together if they are in both maps
 * 
 * firstMap = {"Eggs": 3, "Cereal": 1}
 * secondMap = {"Eggs": 10, "Coke": 23, "Cereal": 1}
 * 
 * Answer = {"Eggs": 13, "Coke": 23, "Cereal": 2}
 * Notice that the Eggs are now 13
 * 
 * @param firstMap
 * @param secondMap
 * @return
 */
public Map<String, Integer> mergeAndAddValues(Map<String, String> firstMap, Map<String, String> secondMap) {

    return Stream.of(firstMap, secondMap)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       Map.Entry()::getKey,
                       Map.Entry::getValue,
                       Integer::sum,
                       HashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: Map.Entry()::getKey should be  Map.Entry::getKey

Comment: @tgdavies Correct, but with that fix alone it'll not work. The type of stream elements and return type are incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method arguments are of type `Map<String, String>` and the return type is `Map<String, Integer>`.

In order to fix your method, you need to coerce *entries* that are of type `Map.Entry<String, String>` into *entries* `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`.

It could be done by applying `map()` operation inside the nested stream. Static method `Map.entry()` is used to create a new *entry* based on an existing one. I assume that all string are comprised of digits only, otherwise you need to apply an additional clearing before parsing them.

```
public Map<String, Integer> mergeAndAddValues(Map<String, String> firstMap,
                                              Map<String, String> secondMap) {

    return Stream.of(firstMap, secondMap)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(),
                            Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       Map.Entry::getKey,
                       Map.Entry::getValue,
                       Integer::sum));
}
```

**Note** a flavor of `Collectors.toMap` that doesn't require a `mapFactory` (i.e. a version of `Collectors.toMap` that accepts only three arguments) is used because you'll get a `HashMap` as a result by default.

Providing `HashMap::new` manually doesn't byes you anything, conversely your code becomes a bit more rigid, and if in the future `HashMap` will get replaced with a more performant general purpose implementation of the `Map` you will **not** get it for free, for that your code will need to be changed.

> I even tried making my method static ...
> I am getting from using **Map.Entry()::getKey()**
>
> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

This issue isn't connected with static or instance method, unfortunately it's a rare case when error message isn't very helpful. If you replace these method references with lambdas, then the compiler will correctly point that types `String` and `Integer` are incompatible.

And there's no need for strange manipulations with a syntax, I kindly advise you to get familiar with these tutorials on [**lambdas**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [**method references**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Both **lambda expressions** and **method references** are used to provide an implementation of a *function interface*, which is an interface that defines one and only one *abstract method*. I.e. both *lambda* and *method reference* should implement this *single method*.

All arguments that `Collectors.toMap()` expects are *functional interfaces* built-in in Java.

In the case when implantation of the behavior defined by a *function interface* already exists (*i.e. you have a method somewhere which does what the method declared in the interface is expected to do*), you can make use of it with a **method reference**.

There are four ***kinds of method references*** (quote from the *Oracles's tutorial* referenced above):

- Reference to a static method `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type `ContainingType::methodName`
- Reference to a constructor `ClassName::new`

*Note* that the **syntax** of *method references* doesn't require **parentheses**, neither after a type nor after a method name.

So correct syntax will be `Map.Entry::getKey`, and that is a *reference to an **instance** method of an arbitrary object of a particular type*. I.e. type `Map.Entry` actually implies an element of the stream (an object, not an interface).

**Reminder:** `Entry` is a *nested interface* that represents a *key-value pair*, defined in inside a `Map` interface. Hence, the correct syntax to refer to it `Map.Entry` (without any parentheses).

And `getKey` is one of the instance methods declared by the `Entry` interface.

#### Recap

The correct syntax to define a `Function` (*which is standard **functional interface** expected as the first argument by the* [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) with a ***method reference*** is:

```
Map.Entry::getKey
```

Where the first part before the *double colon* is the *type* of the object that will be passed to a ***function***. And second part is a *method name*.

Parentheses are **never** used after a type in Java (don't confuse the reference to a type with a constructor invocation). And after a *method name* parentheses are dropped because that how the language was designed, and I guess because *method references* are intended to be concise and expressive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map.Entry::getKey` and `Map.Entry::getValue` but the error is caused by something else. `Map.Entry::getValue` and `Integer::sum` return different types.

The definition of `toMap` method explains why:

```java
public static <T, K, U, M extends Map<K, U>> Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper, 
    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper, 
    BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, 
    Supplier<M> mapFactory);
```

In the definition you can see that:

- `valueMapper` has `? extends U` type
- `mergeFunction` has `U` type

Changing the type of firstMap and secondMap from `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Integer>`, there are no errors. This is because the type returned by `Map.Entry::getValue` changes from `String` to `Integer`.

Here the final result:

```java
public Map<String, Integer> mergeAndAddValues(Map<String, Integer> firstMap, Map<String, Integer> secondMap) {
    return Stream.of(firstMap, secondMap)
                 .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::sum, HashMap::new));
    }
}
```